# Is it possible to create some pre-register users when migrate to authentication DB in ASP.NET/Blazor project?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I wonder if it's possible to add users and passwords without have to register them with a form.
I have an existing DB with some users and passwords and I want to transfer it to `aspNetUser`.

I migrated these default tables [into local DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KaYV.png) and I don't understand how to set about 10 existing users with only passwords in these tables.

I only want to "paste" in users and passwords.

I'm using Blazor server template with individual authentication enable.

Comment: Yes.  But with no code, no one can offer much but general advice.  Update your question with your existing DB structure and we will be able to provide you with a better answer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that but manually as a seed to your database.
You can do something like that:

```cs
public class AppIdentityDbContextSeed
    {
        public static async Task SeedAsync(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
        {
            await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole("Administrators"));

            var defaultUser = new IdentityUser { UserName = "your username", Email = "your email" };
            await userManager.CreateAsync(defaultUser, "your password");

            string adminUserName = "Your admin name";
            var adminUser = new IdentityUser { UserName = adminUserName, Email = "your admin email" };
            await userManager.CreateAsync(adminUser, "your admin password");
            adminUser = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(adminUserName);
            await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(adminUser, "Administrators");
        }
    }
```

Then you can use `SeedAsync` method in your `program` class as below:

```cs
public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = CreateHostBuilder(args)
                        .Build();

            using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
            {
                var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
                try
                {
                    
                    var userManager = services.GetRequiredService<UserManager<IdentityUser>>();
                    var roleManager = services.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
                    await AppIdentityDbContextSeed.SeedAsync(userManager, roleManager);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //exception handling
                }
            }

            host.Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
```

Finally check `Startup.cs`, it should be as below:

```cs
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>().AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Comment: Ok, I tried it but my dbo.AspNetUsers remains empty. I'm probably missing out on something...

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake. I've updated the answer. It should be `IdentityUser` instead of `ApplicationUser`. Also check `Startup.cs` as I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Thank you! but I tried your code an it only adds Administrators role in the AspNetRoles table, no users in the ApsNetUsers

Comment: I've tried it and it added users correctly, maybe you need to pass valid passwords for `AspNetUsers` that have uppercase letters and numbers, and valid emails as well? try this credentials and let me know if it works or not `UserName = "user"`, `Email = "user@gmail.com"`, `password="P@ssword1"`

Comment: Ok you're right! Thank you so much, save my day!